# how to use realm-nodejs sdk for creating user in altas-app-services from Mongodb-altas-serverless functions?

Tags: mongodb, authentication, realm

We have a situation where we need to register users from a third party publisher, there are 1m users. We need the following:

1. to allow for a batch process to create users.
2. to crate a user each time a publisher creates a new user (trigger)
3. publisher will call our api's either batch or via a trigger on their end.
4. We need to provide auth details back to the publisher for each user so that publisher can push whatever auth data to client browser so the browser can authenticate via realm SDK and pass auth to our own app.

We are using realm-nodejs sdk for authenticating user but the issue is realm in not supported in altas app-services-functions as they are using nodejs-v10 in their serverless run-time environment.

Please suggest some solution which will fix in our tech stack. Thanks

I have tried to use realm-nodejs-sdk in mongodb-altas-functions but it didn't installed because realm-nodejs-sdk support node version >12.0.0, but altas function uses nodejs v10.
So basically i want to authenticate user using realm-nodejs-sdk.

Comment: Welcome to SO. There are probably 100 different ways to approach this from crafting an app to read a flat file then create users, to leveraging server side code to using third party authentication. The question is pretty vague. Also, SO is for coding specific issues; write some code and when you get stuck, post it and your troubleshooting and we'll take a look. Please take a moment and review [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)